# What is the purpose of a memory Sanity Word?

Tags: c, memory

I have always seen non volatile memory (such as an EEPROM) tagged at the front with a "Sanity" word (first word is set to a special chosen number).  I understand that this can help identify if the data in that NVM is "valid" or not, but I have also seen it used in addition to a CRC of the data.

What is the general purpose of a sanity word (if different from above), and is there any reason to use a sanity word in addition to a CRC/hash?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd guess that the 'sanity word' (a magic number) gives you reassurance that the data is of the type you expect (and the hash tells you it has the correct content).  If you have just the hash (CRC) of the data, you know whether it has been changed, but you don't know whether it is of the type you expect except that the hash matches the data.  Unless you're short of space — really need the extra 4 bytes for something else (which cannot be ruled out in environments where EEPROMs are most often used) — then it is probably safest to stay with both the sanity word and the hash.

Comment: In addition to everything Jonathan Leffler said, suppose you had two different devices that took ROMs.  Having an easy way for the device to check that the right kind of ROM is installed by just looking at the first few bytes could be an advantage to computing a CRC or other digest for the entire ROM, especially if the devices have different addressable ranges.